# How to get size of HitCube generated at walls?

Tags: unity-game-engine, arkit

Im trying to get a size of HitCube generated when you aim at wall in new ARkit 1.5 in Unity. Cant exactly get that, anyone knows maybe?

Comment: No idea, what have you tried?

Comment: I saw in assets exactly same blue cube and followed him. Hes in hierarchy attached to GameObject - GeneratedPlanes, sounds good right? Well it doesn't work like that. It seems like its to the same. I checked dynamically of active objects while running up. I saw one activating when I generated hitcube on wall and it had generated name sth like : EE80-SSX88 etc. not sure if this is the one but can't quite track what exactly creates it and where to get its position and scale